# Can't read the name of the file input yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.3

When I use the var_dump to see the result if I call the name of the file input in the controller I get [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2sM8.png):

> /app/backend/controllers/WithMeetingTrait.php:84:null

This is the view:

```
<div class="custom-file">
  <input type="file" name="image" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" >
  <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01"><?= Yii::t('app', 'Choose file(s)...') ?></label>
</div>
```

and this is the controller:

```
 exit(var_dump(UploadedFile::getInstanceByName( 'image')));
```

I also tried to do this:

```
exit(var_dump($_FILES["image"]));
```

But the result is:

[image]

I don't use a model in this part of project.

Comment: See what's in $_FILES (don't use var_dump in exit, var_dump is a void function) and also did you put ['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']] in your ActiveForm?

Comment: I use `var_dump` in `exit` to get the result returned with by the name of the form, it is true that I miss `['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart / form-data' ]]` but `$ _FILES` is still empty.     Although `$ _POST` returned the result correctly

Comment: @adnenmanssouri please show us your form codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution i found is that I don't put `['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart / form-data']]` in the correct place.
Its a concentration mistake thanks for all.